# What's the word for the idea of something that will happen in the future, sort of like "promise"?

Tags: single-word-requests

So I have this word at the tip of my tongue, I know it starts with a p, and is similar in meaning to "promise", in usage it would be something like

> The only thing I have going for me right now is the <word> that this will happen in the future.

It also has a bit of connection to the meaning of premonition, like it's not an absolute guarantee or promise, and it's sort of a conjecture, but it is hinted at to be preferred to happen in the future.

Comment: I'd guess potential, portent, presentiment, presage, or possibility but there are a lot of options in [a thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/promise)

Comment: I checked out all the majour thesauruses on google already, none of them were helpful, like always. All of the words you listed are similar to what I want, with "portent" being the closest, but it sounds too mystical and ominous. "Probability" is not it as well, but is similar nonetheless.

Comment: Please mention in your question what research you have done and all the words you have considered. There are simple guidelines on how to ask a question, and if you ignore them, it means you waste everybody's time.

Comment: @nollo123 You can indicate the correct answer by clicking its checkmark to accept it.

Comment: This is an instance of foreshadowing, which of course is starting with the wrong letter.  Predestined might work, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### Prospect
>
> The possibility that something good might happen in the future.

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prospect)]

It can be random, like “the prospect of good weather”, or it can be something that can be improved with effort, as in “if he works hard, his  prospects will be good”.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with the bias towards a positive outlook (though 'his prospects look bleak' is an idiomatic counterexample). [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prospect) lists the hopeful and neutral outlooks, but gives the hopeful subsense first.

Answer (score 1):

*The only thing I have going for me right now is the* **perspective** *that this will happen in the future*.

Definition : a view over some distance in space or time; vista; prospect
a view, especially one in which you can see far into the distance.

Example : The concept of sustainable development needs to be further
developed, particularly in a long-term perspective.

Comment: perspective means point of view....particularly **from a long-term perspective**.

Comment: @Lambie : In the sentence *An outline on the planned cooperations and future perspectives will conclude the presentation*, would you replace perspective by point of view ?

Comment: The presentation will conclude with an outline on planned cooperation and future perspectives. Cheers. That's the forbidden fruit of editing.

Answer (score 0):

You have an **inkling** about the future.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inkling)
> *inkling*:
> a feeling that something is true or likely to happen, although you are not certain

It feels an unusual word and the etymology is obscure:

> [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/inkling)
> inkling (n.)
> c. 1400, apparently from the gerund of the Middle English verb inclen "utter in an undertone, hint at, hint" (mid-14c.), which is of unknown origin; perhaps it is related to Old English inca "doubt, suspicion, question, scruple." However the earliest record of the word is as a nyngkiling; and The Middle English Compendium offers that this is not a misdivision of an inkling but rather suggests the word is a nasalized variant of nikking "a hint, slight indication," gerundive of the Middle English verb nikken "to mark (a text) for correction" (mid-15c.), from nik (n.) "a notch, tally"